# Merge content of two pages in one page

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have a website with millions of pages.

```
Page 1: http://example.com/commercial-product-name1
Page 2: http://example.com/commercial-product-name2
page 3: http://example.com/Scientific-name
```

Now

1. Page 1 and 2 are for two different manufacturer but for the same scientific name.
2. Page 1 and 2 are more searchable and they have inbound link to page 3 already, but the visitors usually don't navigate to the scientific name as they dont think it would have valuable info

**The Question**
from SEO perspective:

1. do you recommend to include the content of the scientific-page inside page-1 and page-2 or to keep it in its own page?
2. What is the best scenario to have more traffic to scientific-page

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches for this. One it to redirect traffic and to set the canonical to the scientific URL.

The other is to have the three pages and on the commercial name ones have a small paragraph that says this is the commercial name of scientific name and give them the link to the scientific page. This way you will not have any issue with duplicate content and users will still see a page for each possible name.

Comment: Thanks @Itai, in fact i am using your second suggestion, but it looks people don't pay much attention to scientific link and they don't navigate to it. the links are about medicines, so usually they care about the product itself while much more valuable info is in the scientific page (Which they don't navigate to although there is a link to it in the commercial product itself)

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that it's better to have 10 quality pages than 100 fragmented pages. So I would put product1, product2 and the scientific name all on the same page. Maybe also add some explanation why product1 differs from product2 and why they both share the same scientific name. In that way it's clear for all users who searched for either one of those three things why they landed on that page. And they can read more relevant information as in the old situation where they only could read one out of the three items.

Answer (score 1):

With millions of pages I see no chance for sustainable SEO.

- First, I would noindex all pages which don't get traffic (Analytics to the rescue).
- Second, I would run a broad keyword research to discover which products have search volume. Then I would optimize these product pages for keywords with search volume and allow them to be indexed.